# Bitcoin cash wallet with ability to generate new addresses

Tags: bitcoin-cash, address-generation

I'm looking for a wallet that can generate new addresses. I've seen some wallets that do generate a new receive address for Bitcoin, but I'm not sure if a new address is used when Bitcoin is sent.

I want my transactions to be not directly linked together if someone looked the Bitcoin Cash blockchain.

For that I would need to create multiple wallets? Are there any wallets that have a feature to generate new wallets?

Answer (score 0):

The wallet I use, ElectronCash, has the ability to create multiple adresses. Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash use the same adresses and private key format, so you can use your Bitcoin adresses as Bitcoin Cash adresses.

Bitcoin Cash now also uses the `bech32` address format.

Comment: Bitcoin Cash uses `cashaddr`. It is derived from and similar to `bech32`, but not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions in Bitcoin blockchain are not linked with the ones in Bitcoin Cash blockchain.

Anyway, I will suggest that you use Electrum.org wallet
Create a native segwit wallet , just like the image below.

Bitcoin cash has no segwit addresses, so your public addresses will not even have the same encoding there.

[image]